# Template is missing for signup/create, application/create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, input

I'm currently trying to build a simple form that takes an email  address and puts it in the database as part of a landing page. The form is on `home.html.erb` and is controlled by the `pages` controller.

I'm getting the following error:

> Missing template signup/create, application/create with
>   {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder,
>   :coffee]}. Searched in: *
>   "/Users/me/rails_projects/this_project/app/views"

Here's my code:

`home.html.erb` has:

```
    <%= form_for(@signup) do |f| %>
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.text_field :email %>
        </div>

        <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

`Pages` controller has:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    @title = "Title of my site"
    @signup = Signup.new
  end

end
```

`Signups` controller has:

```
class SignupController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @signup = Signup.new
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @signup = Signup.new(params[:signup])
    if @signup.save
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

end
```

`Signup` model has:

```
class Signup < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :email

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates(:email, :presence => true,
                    :length => {:maximum => 40},
                    :format => {:with => email_regex})

end
```

I'm not sure what's wrong but when I enter a valid email address in the field, this is the error I receive. I've googled around to no avail. Your help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's telling you that a template is missing.

Typically, by default (if you don't call `render()` or `redirect_to()`)  Rails renders the view associated with your action so in your case that would be: `create.html.erb`.

So you should redirect to something that makes more sense if you create a user successfully.

Like:

```
if @signup.save
   redirect_to :root
else
 #...
end
```

By the way I am assuming that you have configured the root path first, like this:

```
root :to => "something"
```

You'll redirect the user where it makes sense to your application.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks very much, Amokrane. Redirected them back to the signups page, my app now takes email addresses successfully!